# Decreasing memory usage for array and SplFixedArray

Tags: php, arrays, memory-management

I was doing some benchmarks between `array()` and `SplFixedArray()` and I run into strange behaviour. At first, look at my simple test (it's actually just edited version from internet, sorry, I can't find original source now):

```
function formatMemoryUsage($usage) {
   $unit = array(' B', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB');
   $factor = floor((strlen($usage) - 1) / 3);

   return sprintf('%.2f %s (%d bytes) ', $usage / pow(1024, $factor), $unit[$factor], $usage);
}

for($size = 1000; $size < 100000; $size *= 2) { 
   echo PHP_EOL . '> Testing size: ' . number_format($size) . PHP_EOL; 
   echo '   Array()' . PHP_EOL;

   for($s = microtime(true), $m = memory_get_usage(true), $container = Array(), $i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) $container[$i] = null; 
      echo '      - Write         - time   : ' . str_pad(microtime(true) - $s, 20, '0') . '     - memory: ' . formatMemoryUsage(memory_get_usage(true) - $m) . PHP_EOL; 

   $s = microtime(true); 
   foreach ($container as $key => $value) {
      $void = $value;
   }
   echo '      - Read          - time   : ' . str_pad(microtime(true) - $s, 20, '0') . PHP_EOL;

   unset($container);

   echo '   SplFixedArray()' . PHP_EOL;

   for($s = microtime(true), $m = memory_get_usage(true), $container = new SplFixedArray($size), $i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) $container[$i] = null; 
   echo '      - Write         - time   : ' . str_pad(microtime(true) - $s, 20, '0') . '     - memory: ' . formatMemoryUsage(memory_get_usage(true) - $m) . PHP_EOL; 

   $s = microtime(true); 
   foreach ($container as $key => $value) {
      $void = $value;
   }
   echo '      - Read          - time   : ' . str_pad(microtime(true) - $s, 20, '0') . PHP_EOL; 

   unset($container);
}
```

Results were kind of expected - `SplFixedArray()` was faster in writing and little bit slower in reading. Things starts to be strange when I put another same `SplFixedArray()` test right after `unset()` of previous one, see the output:

```
> Testing size: 64,000
   Array()
      - Write         - time   : 0.009041070938110400     - memory: 7.50 MB (7864320 bytes) 
      - Read          - time   : 0.004010915756225600
   SplFixedArray()
      - Write         - time   : 0.004639148712158200     - memory: 1.75 MB (1835008 bytes) 
      - Read          - time   : 0.005971908569335900
   SplFixedArray()
      - Write         - time   : 0.005653858184814500     - memory: 1.50 MB (1572864 bytes) 
      - Read          - time   : 0.006288051605224600
```

Why second test use less memory than first one? And hey, I try to add next test and:

```
> Testing size: 64,000
   Array()
      - Write         - time   : 0.008963823318481400     - memory: 7.50 MB (7864320 bytes) 
      - Read          - time   : 0.004142045974731400
   SplFixedArray()
      - Write         - time   : 0.005026102066040000     - memory: 1.75 MB (1835008 bytes) 
      - Read          - time   : 0.005756139755249000
   SplFixedArray()
      - Write         - time   : 0.004483938217163100     - memory: 1.50 MB (1572864 bytes) 
      - Read          - time   : 0.005591869354248000
   SplFixedArray()
      - Write         - time   : 0.004633903503418000     - memory: 1.25 MB (1310720 bytes) 
      - Read          - time   : 0.005697011947631800
```

So I of course try to add more and more and after few more decreasing stoped on *512 kB*. My question here is obvious: **How it is possible and why that when I unset previous object and create new one, used memory is lower?** And it works with normal `array()` too.

Comment: Have you done each test one after the other or have you reset the server in between? Are you sure you don't have any kind of cache working?

Comment: I was trying to do it on two completely different servers and on at least one there was no cache. Well, you can try it yourself on your own enviroment to see if it works for you too...

Comment: hi, do you have the files you used somewhere downloadable? I may try if I have time this next few days.

Comment: Source code is in my post. If you want to reproduce it, just copy `SplFixedArray` test **after** `unset` of previous one and duplicate it. Repeat this as many times as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to go into the engine if we want to understand this. Better: inside of [Zend/zend_alloc.c (The Zend Memory Manager)](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_alloc.c).

The memory allocated by the memory manager is split into chunks of [256 KB](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_alloc.c#ZEND_MM_BLOCK_SIZE).

Upon freeing the SPLFixedArray, [only the first contiguous chunk of memory is freed](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_alloc.c#2113). There always remains a block of 256 KB (some variables) which then accumulates. (which works as the next from the OS allocated memory will be just adjacent to this memory block)

This memory segment is then [marked as free](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_alloc.c#2118) and used the next time when possible instead of allocating new memory from the OS. (and if necessary some memory is appended)

But as at least one block of 256 KB is always freed, we always will notice a difference of 256 KB.

---

When you want to measure memory usage, I really would use `memory_get_usage(false)` as it indicates you how much memory PHP (≠ Zend) needs. (the only thing which counts against the `memory_limit` ini setting)

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, bounty is of course yours.