# Arrays memory management / SplFixedArray iteration / foreach array copy

Tags: php, arrays, spl, arrayaccess, arrayiterator

As I know *foreach* construction does not operate on the array itself, but rather on a copy of it.

You can avoid copy of array by using following construction:

```
reset($array);
while (list($key, $value) = each($array)) {
  echo "$key is $value<br>\n";
}
```

The question is when I create fixed array with:

```
$fixedArrayObj = new SplFixedArray(5);
```

and then iterating it with *foreach* construction - does it creates copy of array and I should still stick to 'while/each' method to avoid it?

Comment: Useful article about [PHP internals: When does foreach copy?](https://nikic.github.io/2011/11/11/PHP-Internals-When-does-foreach-copy.html). Useful? [Using foreach with SplFixedArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942860/using-foreach-with-splfixedarray)

Comment: @RyanVincent thanks, was both was useful but no answer for my question in it.

Comment: If you play with the code provided in [Decreasing memory usage for array and SplFixedArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453915/decreasing-memory-usage-for-array-and-splfixedarray). You can get the memory usage before the `foreach` loop starts and inside the loop. The memory usage remains the same confirming that the `PHP internals` link above applies to `SplFixedArray` as well as for `Array`. i.e. The array is not copied if used directly.